# How to update functions and apps in azure managed application

Tags: azure-managed-app, azure-custom-providers

We have developed an azure managed application.  The managed application is using custom providers, offering end-to-end solutions (api, ...) as azure app service, functions.

Besides the arm templates, the application contains azure functions and azure app services.

The initial deploy is using the marketplace definition itself and initial webdeploy is done through arm template, which works fine.

However, as a publisher, we want to update the functions and apps afterwards (update).

Using devops/deploy is not allowed using our users that where assigned to the managed application as owner.  Stating SCM is not running.

Are there people who already have got this working?  FTP works fine, but we would rather want to use webdeploy.

Comment: Can you provide more information on how you're attempting to update the functions and apps today? You said devops/deploy to do this, but can you help us understand what method you're using and which endpoint you're using?

Comment: The used method was using the scm endpoint and webdeploy.  But in order to be able to do this, I must enable "customer allowed actions", which makes it available to the customer too (and not just the publisher), so this method cannot be used, unless someone can enlighten me.